# TQFP socket for QFP package

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, connector, packages, socket

I'm trying to get data off of this IC, and I'm having trouble finding a suitable package. In addition, I need to test ~5 of these on the same PCB, so I need to use a socket.

The problem is, I need HUNDREDS of pins. (The previous engineer designed a chip with 626 --yes, 626-- pins, which I've gotta deal with). Now I only really need to connect roughly 250 or so of these to test. We tried a PGA package, but it didn't work for a number of reasons.

So I've found a great looking TQFP socket:

[image]

[image]

And a pretty great looking QFP package:

[image]

My only question is, would they work together? They have the same 0.5 mm pitch, and the sizings seem to match. From what I can tell, the only difference is the height of the package itself. We don't even need to close the clamshell of the TQFP socket in our tests, so a taller package shouldn't hurt us.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated! Or if you have other ideas/locations to get a matching package/socket, lemme hear them!

Comment: If you only need to test five, it might be easier just to reflow the chips on and off the board.

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to be looking for both a socket and a package, which implies that the "IC" is not already in a package. Furthermore, it impies that you have the means to put the chip in a package (wire bonder, ec.). So why wouldn't you simply bond the chip out directly to a custom carrier PCB?